# ng-change to change the td background-color if the selected value is greater than 6

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hi I have the following code, it's basically a td with select field. The list inside the select field have values range from 1-10. How can I change the background-color of the td if the selected value is greater than 6?

```
<td>
    {%verbatim%}
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="l.o_value"  ng-change="getRpn(k)"
            ng-options="o.rank as (o.rank+o.generic_value) for o in occ_list">
    {%endverbatim%}
    </select>
</td>
```

Comment: why don't you use `ngIf`? You can make a direct conditional check

Comment: but it will be on the select field right, i want ngIf to be at the td, sorry bit new to Angular

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi referthis link https://plnkr.co/edit/MpHtLHgXNyrNRYnDDzed

```
<td ng-class="{ 'bg-red': item.code > 6 }">
```

Comment: happy coding @vellattukudy

Comment: Hey Gayathri, are you from Kerala?

Comment: Oh you from Malaysia.. You're working in which company there? Am from Singapore

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-class` to establish your condition, like this:

```
 ng-class="{'colored-background': scopeParameter > 6}"
```

Comment: But will it change the td background once i select the value from list AranS?

Comment: what is "colored-background" AranS?

Comment: I made up a CSS class and the scope parameter as well

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-class` to attach a class to `td` based on your condition, like this:

```
 <td ng-class="{'colored-background': l.o_value> 6}">
    {%verbatim%}
    <select class="form-control" ng-model="l.o_value"  ng-change="getRpn(k)"
            ng-options="o.rank as (o.rank+o.generic_value) for o in occ_list">
    {%endverbatim%}
    </select>
</td>
```

This will apply the class on the `td` when your selected value i.e `l.o_value` is greater than 6

Make a class in your css like this:

```
.colored-background {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use ng-style for this
Sample Text

Inside

```
getRpn(n) {
if ($scope.scopeParameter > 6) {
   $scope.myStyle = {'background-color':'blue'};
}
}
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle